# ASP.Net Application

Tags: vb.net

I have a small ASP.Net application that appends records from users connected through internet.
I wish to have the database resided over my computer and users could connect with it through internet.
Is it possible?
Thanks and best regards,
Furqan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You database needs to be somewhere where the web server (the machine hosting the web application) can see.

So, if your web server can see your computer (try pinging it), then you should be OK...

Its not an ideal solution though - what happens when you turn off the PC etc? The ideal solution if its a small application is to store the database on the server that is hosting the web application.

Comment: Thanks
Could you kindly advise me any free service where I could experiment it?
Furqan

Comment: Free hosting? Umm, try google.... http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=free+asp.net+hosting